# Can I bind a vertex attribute index from the vertex shader?

Tags: opengl

On the OpenGL FBO wiki page there is this snippet:

> You can also use layout syntax to define this directly in the shader,
>   as you would for attribute indices:
>
> > ```
> > layout(location = 0) out vec4 mainColor; 
> > layout(location = 1) out vec2 subsideraryInfo;
> > ```

This seems to indicate that attribute indices can be specified within a shader, which would simplify things a bit my removing the need for my code to specify attribute locations and such using `glBindAttribLocation`.

Comment: "I can't seem to find more information on this though." You must not have looked very hard. I searched the very wiki you pointed to for "layout location", and I found several pages that touch on it. The very first page covered UBOs, but the page on [GLSL type qualifiers](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Type_Qualifiers) spells it out for all cases. What information are you looking for specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that starting from GLSL 3.30 (OpenGL 3.3). Read here: http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.3.30.6.clean.pdf (page 35).